# Spark FsHistoryProvider brings log files from two months ago

Tags: apache-spark

Currently, I am using spark2 from HDP2.5. When I check spark2's log message, FsHistoryProvider replaying the old log files. When I track down the application id, and it was last July's log.

Is there any suggestions to change configuration to stop that action?

It caused the error message below.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning behavior can be configured using following options:

- `spark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled` - set to `true` to enable cleaner.
- `spark.history.fs.cleaner.maxAge` - maximum age of application to be retained (default `7d`).
- `spark.history.fs.cleaner.interval` - how often cleaner process should run.

So all you have to do is to enable cleaner and configure remaining options.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already added the configuration those configurations from spark2-defaults, and restarted the spark, but I still have the issue.